# Max Minutes Loop

Tags: php

Return max minute by input

By Maximum 5 Minutes

```
round(date('i'));

Minute = Return
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 4
5 = 5
6 = 1
7 = 2
8 = 3
9 = 4
10 = 5
11 = 1
12 = 2
13 = 3
14 = 4
14 = 5
```

Or if is needed by 10 minutes

```
Minute = Return
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 4
5 = 5
6 = 6
7 = 7
8 = 8
9 = 9
10 = 10
11 = 1
12 = 2
13 = 3
14 = 4
15 = 5
```

How to make a function to return these values?

Example of a function

```
function Time_By_Minutes( $Max_Minute = '', $Time = '' ) {
 return '';
}

echo Time_By_Minutes( 5, time() );
```

or

```
echo Time_By_Minutes( 10, time() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function:

```
function Time_By_Minutes( $Max_Minute = 60, $Time = null ) {
    return (date('i', $Time)-1) % $Max_Minute + 1;
}
```

it defaults to 60 max minutes and current time ;)

Comment: I see an issue with this command when the minute was 00 ( start of the hour ) return 0 should be 5 or 10 depends on $Max_Minute

Comment: in that case, the function is:

return (date('i', $Time)+$Max_Minute-1) % $Max_Minute + 1;

Comment: I'm getting this error using that code PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero